# How to extract anonymous function to named function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eclipse, refactoring, aptana

Are there any tools that allows you to do simple refactoring?

For example extract anonymous function to named functions?

Comment: From the tags, I'm guessing JavaScript.

Comment: @Raynos How to do it in "keyboard" ?

Comment: You need to implement a protocol named "typing" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to refactor javascript, there are a number of refactoring tools out there. [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#JavaScript) has javascript support, so that would be a good place to start.